# Python scikit-learn (find deviance)

Tags: python, scikit-learn

The deviance of Y and its expected value E(Y), estimated by the model constructed in c), measures the goodness of fit of the model. The lower the deviance, the better is the model. Below is the equation of how it should be calculated.

=2∑=1{[()]−[−()]}

If Y = 0, the expression log[Y/exp(E(Y))] will be taken as zero. Employ your own Python program to compute D without using the score() function of the scikit-learn package.

How do I go about doing this question? Please helppp!!

[image: the formula]

Comment: Can you rewrite your definition of *D* please? In the second to last paragraph it says `log[Y/exp(E(Y))]` but I do not see any exponential terms in the definition.

Comment: Hi, sorry as there was a change in the formula therefore [Y/(E(Y))]

Answer (score 0):

What you have is the deviance for a model fitted assuming poisson distribution, you can check [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deviance_(statistics)) for how this definition is derived. Using example from [the poisson regressor](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.PoissonRegressor.html)

```
from sklearn import linear_model
import numpy as np

clf = linear_model.PoissonRegressor()
X = [[1, 2], [2, 3], [3, 4], [4, 3]]
y = [12, 17, 22, 21]
clf.fit(X, y)
```

The deviance is:

```
def calculate_dev(y_true,y_pred):
    return (2*(y_true * np.log(y_true/y_pred) - (y_true-y_pred))).sum()

D = calculate_dev(y,pred)
D
0.03453083031027196
```

Compare with the `score()` function, where it is defined as 1 - dev(model)/ dev(null), as in the [documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.PoissonRegressor.html):

```
clf.score(X, y)
0.99048551488916

nullD = calculate_dev(y,np.mean(y))
1 - D / nullD
0.99048551488916
```